# SPECJBB not working properly with JAVA 11

Tags: java-8, linux-kernel, centos, java-11

I'm running SPECJBB2015 with multiple clients in a system with java 11 and kernel 6. The test is failing with max-jops being 0. But the same test with  1 client is passing and multiple client is working is with java 8. Is there any java dependency for SPECJBB2015?